# How to use PR on GitHub for Laravel Packages?

Tags: php, git, github, laravel-5

When I want to make a pull request for a Laravel package on GitHub I do it at the moment in the following way:

1. Create new Laravel project
2. Require & install the package
3. Delete the add-on files from the project in the vendor folder
4. Fork GitHub and clone files into the project folder
5. Make changes to package and test everything.
6. Add, commit, push and do the pull request.

I find this a bit cumbersome - is that actually the correct way of doing it?

For example if I want create a PR for the [voyager package](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager) I would have to
do the following commands for step 1. & 2.

```
>laravel new create-pr
>cd create-pr
>composer require tcg/voyager
>php artisan voyager:install
```

then remove the folder `tcg/voyager` and clone the fork as new folder `tcg/voyager`.

If I skip `composer require tcg/voyager` and directly clone the fork into `tcg/voyager` I cant install the package because of

[image]

Comment: I use https://github.com/orchestral/testbench

Comment: @JeffPuckett but you still need to install your package in a clean Laravel application to test it, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, fork the official repository `tcg/voyager` into your personal repository `iwasherefirst2/voyager`. Then

1) Create a new Laravel Project

2) Add repository `iwasherefirst2/voyager` to composer.json:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/iwasherefirst2/voyager.git"
    }
],
```

3) Now install `tcg/voyager` with `--pref-source` this will automatically install 
`iwasherefirst2/voyager` into `vendor/tcg/voyager` and setup the git connection.

```
composer require tcg/voyager --prefer-source
```

Now you may change files inside `vendor/tcg/voyager` and push them (they will be pushed to your local repository `iwasherefirst2/voyager).

**Remarks**

1) If you would like to have the package folder in the root of your application `package/voyager`, you may create a symlink like this:

```
ln -s vendor/tcg/voyager package
```

2) To see modified files in vendor you may call `composer status -v`

```
$ composer status -v
You have changes in the following dependencies:
/path/to/app/vendor/symfony/yaml/Symfony/Component/Yaml:
    M Dumper.php
```

3) If you run `composer update` you will get a warning if it overwrites any of your files

```
$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
  - Updating symfony/symfony v2.2.0 (v2.2.0- => v2.2.0)
    The package has modified files:
    M Dumper.php
    Discard changes [y,n,v,s,?]?
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped me tremendously