# composer require findbrok/php-watson-api-bridge giving these error how to solve this my laravel is 8

Tags: php, laravel, ibm-watson

**I am trying to create a bridge with laravel 8 and watson api but i am getting the follwoing error can some please help me here**

````
composer require findbrok/php-watson-api-bridge        

Using version ^1.1 for findbrok/php-watson-api-bridge
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update findbrok/php-watson-api-bridge
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

 Problem 1
   - findbrok/php-watson-api-bridge 1.1.x-dev requires illuminate/support ~5.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
   - findbrok/php-watson-api-bridge[dev-master, v1.1.0, ..., v1.1.2] require guzzlehttp/guzzle 6.2.* -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.2.0, 6.2.1, 6.2.2, 6.2.3] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^7.0.1).
   - findbrok/php-watson-api-bridge 1.2.x-dev is an alias of findbrok/php-watson-api-bridge dev-master and thus requires it to be installed too.
   - Root composer.json requires findbrok/php-watson-api-bridge ^1.1 -> satisfiable by findbrok/php-watson-api-bridge[v1.1.0, ..., 1.2.x-dev (alias of dev-master)].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to 
specific versions.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.```
````

Comment: Can some one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the package is old and no longer maintained.
The problem is Laravel 8 installs Guzzle Http with the version 7.
But the package you're trying to install is compatible with Guzzle until version 6. 
You may downgrade Guzzle in your root composer.json, but I wouldn't recommend it. It may break the framework.
Another solution is trying to make a PR to the package to make it compatible with Laravel 8, or use Laravel version 7

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48115694/how-to-use-pr-on-github-for-laravel-packages